# What need to be done for calling web-methods that requires digital signature

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-3.5, digital-signature

I am working on this application that will call a web service developed by Company ABC. Here are few requirements that they have described.

> The data passed to web service methods & the data returned in response is digitaly signed. It is client application responsibility to digitaly sign request data & also verify the digital signatures on responses coming back from our system.

I have only used calls to web servcies without any digital signing requirements. Typically I will just add a web-reference to web-service in my project, instantiate the object and call web-methods.
Now that I have to digitally sign request and verify digital signature on response, what extra measures will I have to take? Will I need any more information regarding digital signatures (certificates or PKI type stuff) from Company ABC before I can actually start calling their web-methods?

Comment: You should try to simply use "Add Service Reference" to the provided WSDL. It may "just work", with no extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Digital signatures myself, but I just search MSDN and this is what I found:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529260.aspx

Comment: You can also check out: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996951.aspx#wssecauthwse_topic5